# Visual Studio 2019 OneNote, Неразделяемые пробелы

Tags: visual-studio

Есть проблема с OneNote с Visual Studio 2019

Я разработчик и использую OneNote для хранения наработок кода. На Python и C# и ABAP

Все прекрасно работает когда я переношу код например из Visual Studio 2019 в OneNote.

А вот когда переношу обратно то есть проблема. OneNote ставит вместо обычных пробелов ставит неразделяемые пробелы по всему тексту.

И Visual studio 2019 не понимает эти пробелы. Мне приходится сначала скопировать код в MSWORD а потом в Visual studio 2019.

Тогда все работает.

Такая же проблема есть с VSCODE но там есть расширение fix irregular whitespace, который все проблемы решает и заменяет пробелы на обычные.

Для Visual studio 2019 тоже есть расширение по замене. Но оно удаляет только в конце текста.  А в самом тексте нет. 
У ABAP нет проблем. Его редактора заменяет такие пробелы автоматически по умолчанию. 
Собственно вопрос.

Как научить удалять/заменять VisualStudio 2019 эти пробелы на обычные по всему тексту?

Спасибо.

p.s. В самом oneNote нет никаких настроек по этому поводу.

Comment: Решение - не использовать OneNote для хранения кода. Используйте github например.

Comment: Нет это не подходит к сожалению. Это мои повседневные нароботки кода. Куски кода И мне они нужны для работы. Только мне. Другим они не нужны. И быстрый поиск по ним. У меня там кода на сотни мегабайт. oneNote Подходит во всем за исключением этой проблемы. Которая как бы решается копированием в ворд а потом в VS. Все остальные среды разработки так или иначе умеют менять эти неразделяемые пробелы. Мне лишь нужно научить это делать VS.  Пока что я буду копировать через ворд до решения этой проблемы.

Comment: Еще раз: вы используете неподходящий инструмент. Лучше использовать специализированные сервисы сниппетов: например github gists или pastebin. То что некоторые IDE умеют заменять неразрывные пробелы на обычные - это исключение, никакая IDE не обязана это делать. Использованием OneNote вы только усложняете себе жизнь.

Comment: еще раз. Большая просьба не советовать мне что-то другое вместо того что я пользуюсь уже много лет и меня устраивает. Мне сейчас пришлось вирнуться к C# И там я столкнулся с этой проблемой. Мне нужно решить этот вопрос на уровне VS.  Верояно на уровне расширений. VSCode решает ээтот вопрос. Это такой же продук MS как и VS. Если Вы точно знаете ответ на вопрос что это сделать в VS невозможно. Значит я приму этот ответ и буду пропускать через WORD. github абсолютно мне не подходит для моих задач.

Comment: Проблема частично решилась установкой расширения batchreplace 1 раз записываешь что на что менять и потом по 1 клику меню все меняется.  Значит расширением можно исправить. Достаточно написать расширение которое при сохранение файла будет заменять неразделенныйе пробелы на обычные. Как это сделали в VSCODE Звучит легко но, но сунулся в то как делать расширения. Совершенно не понимаю как это все работает.

Comment: Мне кажется проще написать программу, которая будет следить за буфером обмена из заменять в нем пробелы на правильные.

Comment: Проблема не воспроизводится. Пробелы остаются пробелами. Зато отступы заменяются на пробелы, а окончания строк дублируются.

Answer (score 2):

**Вариант 1** - вставить как текст. **Форматирование не сохраняется.**

Если в OneNote вставлять код из VisualStudio или из VSCODE именно как текст "Сохранить только текст", то при обратном копировании неразрывные пробелы вставлять не будут. Но есть минус, что подсветка синтаксиса при таком копировании в OneNote будет отсутствовать.
При таком решении можно избежать последствий.

### [image: OneNote вставить как текст "Сохранить только текст"]

**Вариант 2** - Goole Документы как промежуточная точка копирования. **Форматирование сохраняется.**

1. Скопировать текст из VS в Goole Документы
2. Скопировать текст из Goole Документ в OneNote
3. После этого код можно копировать обратно в VS без проблем.

Comment: да, я так делаю только через MS WORD.

Comment: Я пробовал через Word. Через него получается если только копировать из OneNote в Word, а только потом в VS, в обратную сторону у меня не работает. Т. е. придется каждый раз при копировании из OneNote копировать в Word, а по моей схеме достаточно будет 1 раз скопировать из Google Документов в OneNote и потом уже можно копировать напрямую из OneNote в VS.
Но я с Вами согласен, хотелось бы более простую и удобную схему.

Comment: Да, именно так. Проблема имеет решение. Хотелось бы удобств.  Кому интересно вот видео проблем. Я их послал в ru поддержку microsoft. https://youtu.be/ArBuQmmFxo0    https://youtu.be/92ocJrWLt-U